# Custom name with \pgfmathsetmacro

Tags: pdftex, pgfmath

I have a function that have parameters that need to calculate large numbers
at some point in that function, I want to use `pgfmath` to cumulate the data (since counters don't have enough range):

```
...
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true}
\pgfmathsetmacro\csname Total#1\endcsname{\csname Total#1\endcsname + #2} %does not work probably missing a \expandafter
\pgfmathsetmacro\TotalContractH{\TotalContractH + #2}
\pgfmathsetmacro\temp{#2 * #3}
\pgfmathsetmacro\TotalContractC{\TotalContractC + \temp}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}
...
```

How can I acheive the dynamic name for that thing. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `\pgfsetmacro\csname Total#1\endcsname{...}`, the first argument of `\pgfsetmacro` is `\csname` and not the dynamic macro. Therefore, `\csname` needs to be expanded first:

```
\expandafter\pgfsetmacro\csname Total#1\endcsname{...}
```

Answer (score 3):

Add, in the preamble,

```
\newcommand\pgfmathsetmacroname[1]{%
  \expandafter\pgfmathsetmacro\csname#1\endcsname
}
```

Then something like

```
\pgfmathsetmacroname{Total#1}{\csname Total#1\endcsname + #2}
```

ought to work.

A more complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\pgfmathsetmacroname[1]{%
  \expandafter\pgfmathsetmacro\csname#1\endcsname
}

\newcommand\settotal[2]{%
  \pgfmathsetmacroname{Total#1}{#2}%
}
\newcommand{\usetotal}[1]{\csname Total#1\endcsname}

\begin{document}

\settotal{A}{1}% starting value
\settotal{A}{\usetotal{A}+2}
\settotal{A}{\usetotal{A}*3}

\usetotal{A}

\end{document}
```

This prints, as expected,

> 9.0

Answer (score 2):

`\csname <stuff>\endcsname` needs to be expanded before resulting in `\<stuff>`; easily achievable via a couple of `\expandafter`s. Also, create macros to make your life a little easier:

> 10
>   30.0

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\newContract}[2]{%
  \expandafter\pgfmathsetmacro\csname Total#1\endcsname{#2}%
}
\newcommand{\addtoContract}[2]{%
  \def\contractAssign{\expandafter\pgfmathsetmacro\csname Total#1\endcsname}%
  \expandafter\contractAssign\expandafter{\csname Total#1\endcsname + #2}%
}

\newcommand{\contractValue}[1]{\csname Total#1\endcsname}

\begin{document}

\newContract{ABC}{10}\contractValue{ABC}

\addtoContract{ABC}{20}\contractValue{ABC}

\end{document}
```